# Find_libraries does not find precompiled library under given path (CMAKE)

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMAKE project which I have configured for cross compiling via a toolchain file for ARM architecture.
For the project I need to include some precompiled libraries which are under the same path as the project.
Example:

.
├── build
│   └── CMakeFiles
├── doc
│   ├── html
│   └── latex
├── external
│   ├── includes
│   ├── libs <--- location precompiled libs
│   ...
├── include
├── source
└── test

In CMAKE I use
find_library(${LIB_VAR} NAMES ${LIB} HINTS ${LIB_PATH} )

in a loop to include ${lib} under the path ${LIB_PATH}. What I get are just "-NOTFOUND".
Does the toolchain file override the HINTS in find_library or have I configured something wrong?

PS: The precompiled libs are static (.a) if thats important...

I copied the precompiled libs into the configured sysroot and everything works fine.
Of course thats just a quick and dirty fix and horrible to maintain.

Comment: Are you sure that `${LIB_PATH}` is correct? Maybe you have specified a relative path and you are executing the script in a different root.

Comment: I already tested this with by printing ${LIB_PATH} --> Output: <Path to project>/external/libs/

Looks fine

Comment: "Does the toolchain file override the HINTS in find_library" - Toolchain could add a **prefix** to the search paths. Look for variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html) in the toolchain. You could also pass `--debug-find` option to `cmake`, so it will print exact paths it searches.

Comment: @Tsyvarev checked CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM -->not defined.
 Search path is:
~/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf_sdk-buildroot/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/<lib> -->rootfs of my target

Comment: For library it should be `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` variable. According to output, this variable is actually in effect.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are the hero of the day :) I set the variable via  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)  in my CMakeList and everything works as expected! Post your comment as an answer and I mark it as answered. Thank you very much, I searched for hours!